# Attach LLDB to app on iPhone connected to computer - Command line

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, lldb

So I know how to connect the LLDB debugger to an app running on my iPhone from Xcode, but I would like to be able to do this from the command line.

How could I achieve this over command line? I would prefer to do it by app name, but I'm just as happy to do it via bundle identifier. PID probably won't work since I won't have a reliable way of getting it.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71753223/19309398

Answer (score 2):

lldb doesn't know how to start up a debug session from your host Mac to an iOS device.  Xcode does that job for us, and then lldb just talks to the communication channel it has been given.  The only official way to access this functionality is through Xcode.